# Accessing DLC in Fallout 3 Game of the Year Edition (PC)

Tags: pc, fallout-3

I'm having trouble accessing the DLC in Fallout 3 Game of the Year Edition on PC. I completed the game and then installed the DLC from disc 2. I then re-inserted Disc 1 and loaded all of the files for the "Data Files" option in the launcher window.

How do I access my DLC? when I load my most recent save nothing pops up saying new quests or options are available. I've tried starting a new game and I've searched through the downloads option in the main menu but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DLC is just scattered around the wasteland. In order to find the locations turn on your radio and you will see a bunch of new radio broadcasts. Listening to said broadcasts will make the DLC locations appear on your map (with the exception of Broken Steel). You can also go [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_add-ons) and read the main article for each of the DLC's listed. The first quest in the main article has a "given by" section which will tell you how to access them:

[image]

As a side note when you reloaded the first disk after installing the dlc you should have gotten notifications that a new signal has appeared on your radio. So hopefully this isn't actually a bug.

The physical locations of the DLC (on your pc) are:

> ```
> %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Xlive\DLC (Windows XP)
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XLive\DLC (Windows Vista & Windows 7)
> ```

Just in case you want to check if they actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wander the Wasteland for a short while, you should start picking up some radio signals. If they don't appear, try looking at the radio in your Pipboy. If that still doesn't work, start a new game and head off to Megaton. If they STILL haven't appeared, then you will probably need a reinstall.